# MVC 4 - REST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, rest

I am trying to build REST API.

I have the below model

```
 public class FrequentQueryRequest
        {
            public string[] Fields { get; set; }
            public DateRange Range { get; set; }

        }

        public class DateRange
        {
            public DateTime? From { get; set; }
            public DateTime? To { get; set; }
        }
```

and my controller

```
public FrequentQueryReport FrequentReport(FrequentQueryRequest request)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < request.Fields.Count(); i++)   --- **Error (request is null)** 
    {
          Fieldname = request.Fields[i];
          sqlconnector.Distribution(Fieldname, request, ref FieldDistribution);
    }
}
```

and I have the below config

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "API",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I made the request using the below URL **[UPDATED]**

```
http://localhost:63591/FrequentReport?Fields=Employer&From=2014-10-10&To=2014-10-10
```

In my controller i am getting request value as null

What went wrong ? Can any one help me ?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't you miss an `&` between `From` parameter and `To` parameter in your url ? So you may try `http://localhost:63591/FrequentReport?Fields=Employer&From=2014-10-10&To=2014-10-10`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, I have updated the request. But still i am facing the same problem

Comment: It also looks like you have a typo in your controller : `Frequesntreport` instead of `FrequentReport`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus  : http://localhost:63591/FrequentReport?Fields=Employer&From=2014-10-10&To=2014-10-10  Tried this too. But still not working

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to make it working (but in my opinion dirty) is to change your action to:

```
public FrequentQueryReport FrequentReport([FromUri]FrequentQueryRequest request)
```

but you can always use "biding". Have a look on this article:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

**Model Change**

```
[DataContract(Name = "frequentQueryRequest", Namespace = "")]
public class FrequentQueryRequest
{
    [DataMember(Name = "fields", Order = 1, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]      
    public string[] Fields  { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "dateRange", Order = 2, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public DateRange Range  { get; set; }   
}

[DataContract(Name = "dateRange", Namespace = "")]
public class DateRange
{
    [DataMember(Name = "from", Order = 3, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "to", Order = 4, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller change**

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("FrequentReport")]
public FrequentQueryReport FrequentReport(FrequentQueryRequest  request)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < request.Fields.Count(); i++) 
    {
          Fieldname = request.Fields[i];
          sqlconnector.Distribution(Fieldname, request, ref FieldDistribution);
    }
}
```

URL has to be :  `http://localhost:63591/{controllername}/FrequentReport`

Request Body:

```
{
    "fields": [{Employer, JobTitle,}],
    "dateRange": {
        "from": "2014-02-20T19:24:26+05:30",
        "to": "2014-08-20T19:23:41+05:30"
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the request to:

```
http://localhost:63591/FrequentReport?Fields=Employer&Range.From=2014-10-10&Range.To=2014-1‌​0-10
```

See the `Range.From` and `Range.To`. Otherwise you will have both dates set to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/701182/A-Custom-Model-Binder-for-Passing-Complex-Objects

I am using the custom ModelBinder to do this

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(FieldValueModelBinder))] FrequentQueryRequest request
```